# Static methods or static functions?

Tags: terminology, functions, static-methods

I was just reading https://stackoverflow.com/questions/155609/what-is-the-difference-between-a-method-and-a-function and all of a sudden, the thing came to my mind was the static methods.

As static methods are no way associated with an object how can it be called as static methods (almost all developers do)? Is my understanding about the methods/functions is correct?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

(Using Java terminology): Static methods *can* be associated with static members (members of the `class` object). If the methods don't access static members (nor IO resources or anything else that could change state), of if those members are `final` primitives or immutable objects (essentially constants), then such static methods could be called functions, but in general, because they potentially *could* access the `class` object's members, they're usually called static *methods*.

**In order to count as a function, a method must be independent of any state**; it must not cause any side effects nor be affected by any side effects. When called with specific parameters, it must always return the same result. Otherwise it's not a pure function.

That is, the following `area` is a function:

```
class MyClass {
    static final double pi = 3.14;
    static double area(double r) {
        return pi * r * r;
    }
}
```

while the following `getCallCount` is not a function:

```
class MyClass {
    static int callCount = 0;
    static int getCallCount {
        return ++callCount;
    }
}
```

In general, mutable (non-`final`) static members should be used with caution - someone would say that they should not be used at all - because they make a *global state* to the program, which likely turns out to be a bad design choice in the long run. There are exceptions, but be careful...

You don't even need static members to make **static non-functions**: `System.nanoTime()` is definitely not a pure function (because it returns different value on successive calls), even though it only accesses the computer's clock, not any static members.

Confusingly enough, you could also make **non-static pure functions**:

```
class MyClass {
    final double pi = 3.14;
    double area(double r) {
        return pi * r * r;
    }
}
```

Now, although not `static` any more, `area` is still a pure function: it doesn't touch anything that could change. The fact that you would have to create an instance of `MyClass` to access `area` doesn't reduce its "functionness". Indeed, one could argue that this kind of pure functions should always be made static.

Answer (score 4):

> As static methods are no way
>   associated with an object how can it
>   be called as static methods (almost
>   all developers do)? Is my
>   understanding about the
>   methods/functions is correct?

That's an abuse of language. In C++ :

- a **member function** is a function associated with a type or instances of a type. It can be:

  - **static** : associated with the type itself, not with instances
  - **non-static** : associated with an instance of the type. They can be :
  - **virtual** : can be redefined by a child class of the type
  - **non-virtual** : cannot be redefined by a child class (but can be "hidden", often trigerring a compilation warning)
- a **method** is a **virtual member function** that cannot be static by definition

The problem is that some post-C++ languages like Java, a all (non-static) member functions are virtual. So people started to say those are methods. As they didn't needed non-virtual member-functions, they only used the word method for any function that is member of a class.
Now, in those languages, types are also objects, are one instance, so you can say that their static members are in fact methods of the unique object represeting the type. (I'm not sure that's correct for any dynamic language)

Anyway, from your perspective, static member functions(or method if you prefer) should always be perceived as independant of the objects of the type they are member of, but implicitely associated with the type itself (whatever the implementation of that meaning is - whatever the language).

Answer (score 0):

I agree with you. I usually call them procedures, since they are neither methods (associated with a dynamic object), nor functions (side-effect free).